# How to remove a tuple in an integer tuple, if its last element is "0", using Python itertools?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, python-itertools

I have the following code to create a tuple contains multiple tuples with integer pairs:

```py
iterable = (
    tuple(zip([0, 1, 2], _))
    for _ in product(range(9), repeat=3)
)
next(iterable)  # First element is not needed
print(list(iterable))

# This code produces: [((0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 1)), ... , ((0, 8), (1, 8), (2, 8))]
```

But I need that if last element of a tuple is "0" (e.g. (0, 0) or (2, 0)), I have to remove that tuple. So new list should be like this:

```py
[((2, 1),), ... , ((1, 2), (2, 7)), ((1, 2), (2, 8)), ... , ((0, 8), (1, 8), (2, 8))]
```

I actually achieved this goal by the following code but it is not the correct way I think, I don't know:

```py
x = ()
for i in iterable:
    y = ()
    for j in i:
        if j[-1] != 0:
            y += (j,)
    x += (y,)
print(list(x))
```

How can I do this with `itertools` module and in one line, if possible? If needed, I can change the code at the top of this question, to create the desired list in one line.

Thank you.

Comment: what's the logic behind your code? could you explain what are those tuples representing/looking like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `filter()` to remove the elements ending in `0` from the result of `zip()`.

```
iterable = (
    tuple(filter(lambda x: x[-1] != 0, zip([0, 1, 2], _)))
    for _ in product(range(9), repeat=3)
)
```

Comment: This code gives the error ```NameError: name 't' is not defined```.

Comment: except `t` is a tuple of tuple, so you cannot check if t is equal to zero

Comment: @serhatcelik I misunderstood where you wanted to check for `0`, I've updated the answer.

Comment: @Barmar Yes. This is the answer to my question. I can't believe how did i not think of that :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

More itertoolish and shorter+faster, using [`compress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress):

```
iterable = (
    tuple(compress(zip((0, 1, 2), p), p))
    for p in product(range(9), repeat=3)
)
```

Also:

- Don't use name `_` when you *do* use the value, it's the conventional name for values we *don't* use.
- Use *tuple* `(0, 1, 2)`, so Python can always simply load that as a constant instead of having to build a new list `[0, 1, 2]` every time. Or use `enumerate`:

  ```
  iterable = (
      tuple(compress(enumerate(p), p))
      for p in product(range(9), repeat=3)
  )
  ```

A benchmark:

```
 386.0 ± 2.2 μs  Kelly_enumerate
 509.8 ± 3.2 μs  Kelly_zip
 751.6 ± 6.2 μs  Barmar
```

Code:

```py
from timeit import timeit
from statistics import mean, stdev
from collections import deque
from itertools import *

def Kelly_zip():
    iterable = (
        tuple(compress(zip((0, 1, 2), p), p))
        for p in product(range(9), repeat=3)
    )
    return iterable

def Kelly_enumerate():
    iterable = (
        tuple(compress(enumerate(p), p))
        for p in product(range(9), repeat=3)
    )
    return iterable

def Barmar():
    iterable = (
        tuple(filter(lambda x: x[-1] != 0, zip([0, 1, 2], _)))
        for _ in product(range(9), repeat=3)
    )
    return iterable

funcs = Kelly_zip, Kelly_enumerate, Barmar

expect = list(Barmar())
for f in funcs:
    assert list(f()) == expect

times = {f: [] for f in funcs}
def stats(f):
    ts = [t * 1e6 for t in sorted(times[f])[:10]]
    return f'{mean(ts):6.1f} ± {stdev(ts):3.1f} μs '

consume = deque(maxlen=0).extend
for _ in range(100):
    for f in funcs:
        t = timeit(lambda: consume(f()), number=10) / 10
        times[f].append(t)

for f in sorted(funcs, key=stats):
    print(stats(f), f.__name__)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=tVSxjtQwEG2o_BVDdTbKLQknHRApDS2fEEWRNxkfFo5jbAftsrovobkGenoqPoAP4GuwHe_ucaIAISIlUmbeeN48P_vjZ7P3b2Z9d_dp8eLyxY9Hz4WdJ_ByQulBTma2Pv-RlHGee-m8HNwxOyHXRYiP-H6FDLNSOHg56xNmxHcLrlnp0fp5VqfcE0JGFPAaldr3H6ShrCYQngjkW4XQAE2B-PjFKKTDPBmLztEIp2UBVQHPWAEmveyEFrMFA1KDsfO4DJ5arm-Qvgwwiwa5b65W8Pq16BerT43v80K9TCHq8W_YnYv-B7FX3E7c_gEfIVVIUsWn7chhV8Ouvaw6eNxAUC4q2GYFuwJ69oBl_w8sxaKDTZrz1hYP1SzyFITgzgTPBLAK7qLH2RiJHETkkBZbZ-XOBQ-tSBFA0DSw1hMSvRp7HkQNbQe_lt8m4aKFHRVZOB_RbbAhVHid8D7iXbAmjjQt14qOtXVVdt39OcXFIVqfesfq600lbuHbFzikc5BiVyn2_auDC0KGcBjCzKFVOgp04juFuinZBnce9UhOWq8aV2WZ-f1OgMQ7rLUezLyzNeQmSZMCgsZbtE1VMngKVXkuzCNtuDGhM_WMnFXOY6deBbzFfZPUylyMldrTo34FiE3faz5h37P1_sjXyPE6-Qk)

Comment: I didn't know these informations. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @serhatcelik Also note the benchmark I added now.